# Windows 10 Creators Update (1703) crashes our application

Tags: c++, windows, windows-10

Our users are experiencing crashes when Windows 10 Creators Update (1703) is automatically installed through Windows Updates.  The Windows application of ours is a multilevel, C++ WinForms application.  The application can start, but if we click on certain menus, it crashes.  Appears to be a graphics issue or something to do with fonts, perhaps.  Why?

Comment: so, what is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the Windows 10 1703 update was applied, the installer *replaced* the Windows/Fonts directory and *did not include shortcuts* to fonts included elsewhere in Windows.

In our case, our application was needing *Lucida Sans Typewriter* font, which had been registered with Windows, but located in a bundled JRE for IBM Client Access off Program Files (Our application uses some IBM Client Access components).

***Shortcuts* of the *Lucida* fonts were in the Windows/Fonts directory before the update, but absent after the update** (which caused our application to crash).

**The Fix:** We had to copy/paste all the *Lucida* fonts (there are 8 of them) required from the embedded JRE/lib/fonts directory into the Windows/Fonts directory to resolve the issue.  We found if we did this before the 1703 update or after, our application continued to work.

**The Lesson:** We are going to ensure our applications use fonts that we control 100%, by copying them into Windows/Fonts during install.